# String chomping match expression with bound variable

Tags: string, erlang, pattern-matching, design-patterns

The following shell sessions shows some behavior I would like to understand:

```
1> A = "Some text".
"Some text"
2> "Some " ++ R = A.
"Some text"
3> R.
"text"
4> B = "Some ".
"Some "
5> B ++ L = A.
* 1: illegal pattern
```

Surely statements 2 and 5 are syntacticially identical? I would like to use this idiom to extract some text from a string, where `B` is being read in from a configuration file. Is this possible, and what syntax should I use instead of that shown in 5) above?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The `LHS ++ RHS` pattern is expanded at compiletime to `[ lhs0, lhs1, lhs2 | RHS]` (where `LHS =:= [lhs0, lhs1, lhs2]`, and the compiler refuses to do this for anything but literal strings/lists. In theory it could do this for variables, but it simply doesn't right now.

I think in your case you need to do:

```
Prefix = read_from_config(),
TestString = "Some test string",
case lists:prefix(Prefix, TestString) of
    true ->
        %% remove prefix from target string
        lists:nthtail(length(Prefix), TestString);
    false ->
        different_prefix
end.
```

Comment: Ah, the joys of syntactic sugar! Thanks.

Comment: The compiler can't expand variables at compiletime as it doesn't how to expand them.

Comment: One can imagine implementing this case by expanding to a runtime traverse-the-two-lists-in-parallel, return RHS tail when you run out of matching LHS, otherwise don't match kind of operation.

Comment: @archaelus Mind opening a feature request at http://bugs.erlang.org/? I'd love to back it up and help get this behaviour also at runtime!